# Signing into my Offices Windows based Server (16.04)

Tags: networking, server, windows-7, samba

I have begun a new job, and thankfully they are allowing me to use my personal computer *assuming I can connect it to their server.*

I cannot for the life of me find what I'm meant to do. Some tutorials have suggested I can connect if I find the Server IP address, which I *may* have found, but when I enter the number (labled as IPv4 Gateway or IPv4 DHCP Server or IPv4 DNS Server depending on where I look) there is no progress, which might mean I'm doing something wrong, or doing the right thing with the wrong IP.

Even tutorials about using Connect to Server don't work, as my version of Connect to Server looks like this...

[image: I've seen screenshots where there are dropdown menus and lots of other functions that aren't on my machine]

and as I said, I don't know how I'm meant to find the server address.

[image: This might be something?]

One thing I have successfully done is change my workgroup = WORKGROUP to the domain name in /etc/samba/smb.conf, but doing that hasn't changed anything and whenever I search for tutorials, the closest I can find are about setting up a server and then letting Windows computers onto it.

Comment: If your company said this would be okay, it would seem to me that someone, perhaps your System Administrator would have the information required for you to do this. Many times, this is done by logging into their domain server, or via VPN.

Comment: Just for the record "connect to their server" is very vague.  This could be anything from what you are looking into ("Connecting to their file server"), over "connect to their VPN", to "Connect using Remote Desktop".

What would be best is to describe how your co-workers "connect to their server".  That would give us a hint to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Click connect to server and type the following

```
smb://network/server
```

Where network/server is the file server you are trying to access (ask your network admin) once you've done that it will ask you for login credentials, you can also ask your network admin for that as well, and you should be away!

Quick Note: If you are remote working (which it doesn't look like you are) you may require a VPN connection to connect you into the company's local network before you can access the file server, alternatively some company's will provide access to the file server over the internet and you could mount it that way